# How to transpose data from rows to column in excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2010, transpose

I have data like the following,

Cell
A1 = item1 B1 = item2 C1= item3 D1 = item1_price E1= item2_preice F1 = item3_price
A2 = item4 B2 = item5 C2 = item6 D2 - item4_price E2 = ite5_price F2 = item6_price

I am expecting the output to be

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | item1_price |
| item2 | item2_price |

and so on, any idea as to how to do this on excel?

Answer (score 1):

The Transpose() function selects an array and transposes it.
You would have to select everything and excel does it by its own.
There's another way, where you can copy data with ctrl+c, paste it with ctrl+v, press ctrl again and then T, that also transposes.
Hope it helps